# what does resetStandardUserDefaults really do?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsuserdefaults

I am developing an iphone app which has the ability of "add to bookmark/favorite"

But each one of these bookmark has a "status" subtitle or field, the "status" are constantly updated in open jSon database, so in the bookmark table view, when a user clicked an "Update" button, it will send a request to the server and pull out the most updated "status" for every bookmark.

Then when the user click a different view, it will save all of the new status into userDefault, I did it by doing the following in "viewWillDisappear()":

```
NSUserDefaults * defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setObject:myObject forKey:@"myServiceList"];
[defaults synchronize];
```

The above works fine, and the data is saved.

But afterward when I go back to the bookmark view, and then click on other view again, it will CRASH! It won't get pass the following line of code (so it works on 1st time, but not 2nd time):

```
[myDict setObject:[myService objectForKey:@"status"] forKey:@"status"];
```

After looking at the userDefault API, I tried adding the following line of code to solve the problem, and it works PERFECT!

```
NSUserDefaults * defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setObject:myObject forKey:@"myServiceList"];
[defaults synchronize];
//I added the following
[NSUserDefaults resetStandardUserDefaults];
```

Even tho it solve my problem, but I don't really get how it solve it, the documentation said it "Synchronizes any changes made to the shared user defaults object and releases it from memory."

Does that mean that my "myServiceList" was in use, and I will have to release it from memory before I can use it again?

Can someone please help me understand this problem?

Thank You!

Edited:
Here is my viewWIllDisappear() of my bookmark view, if I switch to other view from bookmark view, it will be fine, then when I go back to bookmark view and switch to other view again, it will crash:

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    NSLog(@"start saving data");
    NSUserDefaults * defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSMutableArray * defaultArray = [[defaults objectForKey:@"myServiceList"] mutableCopy];
    for (NSString *key in self.tableContents) 
    {
        for(NSMutableDictionary *myService in [tableContents objectForKey:key])
        {
            for(NSMutableDictionary *myDict in defaultArray)
            {
                if([[myDict objectForKey:@"serviceNumber"] isEqualToString:[myService     objectForKey:@"serviceNumber"]])
                {
                    //The following line is where it will crash
                    [myDict setObject:[myService objectForKey:@"status"] forKey:@"status"];
                    NSLog(@"updated");
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    [defaults setObject:defaultArray forKey:@"myServiceList"];
    [defaults synchronize];
    //[NSUserDefaults resetStandardUserDefaults];
}
```

Comment: You did not show "myObject" - it is an NSArray or a NSMutableArray? Also, you are using ARC or not?

Comment: sorry, I just used "myObject" to simplify things up, but this "myObject" should be equivalent to "defaultArray in the above. And Yes, I am using ARC. It is NSMutableArray.

Comment: Generally, when you save a default, you want a immutable object - so try using "setObject:[NSArray arrayWithArray:defaultArray]" - I'm pretty sure standard defaults does not copy the objects, and you don't want to go mutating something behind its back.

Comment: Still doesnt work unless I uncomment "//[NSUserDefaults resetStandardUserDefaults];". P.S: Sorry, I re-read my question, the crash occurs at "[myDict setObject:[myService objectForKey:@"status"] forKey:@"status"];", not "[defaults setObject:defaultArray forKey:@"myServiceList"];"

Comment: Whether it fixes THIS problem or not, don't go giving user defaults mutable containers - its a really bad idea and may get you into trouble later.

Answer (score 0):

I think what is happening is that by using resetStandardUserDefaults you have forced the flush from memory *including serialising myObject.*

My bet that if you haven't flushed it from memory, the in-memory copy of standardUserDefaults will try to return the original myObject which you gave it for the key "myServiceList".

If you trace things, I suspect that original myObject has either been corrupted somehow or deleted.

By forcing it to give you a fresh myObject, de-serialised back from disk, you are OK.

You could check this by hanging onto another copy of myObject, at the point at which you are calling resetStandardUserDefaults and then compare it with the value you get back for the key "myServiceList" later.